# Grails application spock test failed

Tags: unit-testing, grails, newrelic, spock

I am running `grails 2.2.3` and installed a plugin called "`newrelic:1.0-2.18`.". Now i am getting the error everytime I run the project.

```
| Error Error loading event script from file [/Projects/Front/plugins/cached-resources-1.0/scripts/_Events.groovy] startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/home/user/.grails/ivy-cache/org.spockframework/spock-core/jars/spock-core-0.6-groovy-1.8.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting your .grails folder?